# Most performant strategy for dumping data from large tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, postgresql-9.3

I have been tasked with dumping the data from the 6,800 tables that represent our client base (each one is set up in a 'shard', which are grouped by region in 'clusters').  For the most part these tables are quite small, but there are roughly 500 where the row count is well into the millions.  The total row count across all tables is something like 600 million.

My current process is set up in a concurrent fashion with 16 workers, and I have tried three strategies for dumping these large tables so far:

1. I first attempted to pull the max `id` for the table, and then iterate through in increments of 200k until I hit the max `id` using something like `WHERE id > lowerBound and id <= upperBound`.  This is how our process was working before, and would continue to work other than the fact that they started creating id's that merged a few client identification numbers together, and ranged in the trillions.  So the range of `id`'s in these tables now ranged from 1 to n trillion, making this strategy unviable.
2. I next attempted to use an `ORDER BY id` mixed with a `LIMIT 200000` and I iterated until the row count was less than the `LIMIT`.  This proved to be very expensive, and took a very long time to get through all tables.
3. My latest attempt is to use a `COPY` command to dump large tables to a file, and I then iterate through and process them.  This seems to take as much time as the previous solution, even though it was what our DBA recommended.  This process can take up to 24 hours for all data to be pulled, which is unacceptable.

I'm at my wit's end as to what would be the best way to do this.  Is there a better way to increment through like solutions 1 or 2?

Comment: If I understand things correctly, you need to do some processing of the data rather than just dump it? Otherwise a simple `COPY` would be enough.

Comment: I'm doing some data processing, yes.  Sorry for not being clear about that!

Comment: While reading option 1, I immediately thought of option 2 as the solution. You may want to try again with a lower `LIMIT`. The high limit probably discourages the planner from doing an index scan and it turns to a sequential scan, which may be pretty bad. An `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on those queries would be useful.

Comment: I've decided on doing the processing in the actual query itself due to the processing being just the addition of a few ETL fields.  That way I don't have to worry reading the data I've already written.

Comment: Of course, I suppose there's an index on `id`. Have you tried adjusting `enable_seqscan` and friends?

Comment: I have not yet, I will give that a try!